# Como salvar os dados do formulário em um obj global utilizando o Vuex Vue.js com Laravel 5.8

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2, vuex

Bom galera, em meu primeiro componente eu tenho esse obj pronto.

```
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            valid: false,
            campo: {
                endereco: '',
                numero: '',
                bairro: '',
                cep: '',
                cidade: '',
                estado: '',
                complemento: '',
            }
 }),
```

Eu gostara de pegar o obj campo em outros formularios utilizando o vuex.
minha store no arquivo app.js está assim

```
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        global:{}
    },
    Mutations:{
        setItem(state,obj){
            state.global = obj;
        }
    }
});
```

Minha maior dificuldade é passar esse obj pra a store e depois descobrir a sintaxe correta para utilizar em outro componente.

Answer (score 0):

Para alcançar seu objetivo você pode usar dois helpers do Vuex, o [`mapState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) e o [`mapMutations`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components).

Vamos a um exemplo, o código abaixo vai criar a sua `store` com um form global e uma mutation para setar o form:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(Vuex);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),

  store: new Vuex.Store({
    globalForm: {
      username: ""
    },
    mutations: {
      setForm(state, form) {
        state.globalForm = form;
      }
    }
  })
}).$mount("#app");
```

Então, dentro do seu componente, você pode fazer o seguinte para usar a `mutation` (`this.form` é o seu formulário):

```js
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["setForm"]),

    setFormData() {
      this.setForm(this.form);
    }
  }
};
```

E ai para recuperar o conteúdo do formulário você pode fazer assim em qualquer componente (com `this.globalForm`):

```js
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["globalForm"])
  },
};
```

Talvez seu código não esteja funcionando pois `Mutations` deve ser lowercase quando você cria a `store`.

Comment: Essa sintaxe é para utilizar em projeto 100% vue.js né?
Você poderia modificar para utilizar em vue no Laravel?

Comment: @Rafael, deixei o exemplo de como poderia ser feito, então basta você adaptar para suas necessidades. Eu não manjo como funciona no Laravel.